# Why isn't my mod_rewrite rule working?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

The rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^r/([^/.]+)/?$ generateIssuePage.php?r=$1 [L]
```

When a browser requests myip.com/r/thing, it should redirect to myip.com/r/generateIssuesPage.php?r=thing.

If I just type in www.myip.com/r/generateIssuesPage.php?r=thing, it works fine. But if I request www.myip.com/r/thing, I get 404. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great tool for testing out your htaccess rules is http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Using that tool, it suggests that the htaccess is setup correctly, so that `http://www.myip.com/r/thing` redirects to `http://www.myip.com/r/generateIssuesPage.php?r=thing`

Have you checked that htaccess is working at all for you, but creating a simple global redirect?